# Implement Fileupload control in nopCommerce 2.30

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am a beginner in nopCommerce 2.30. There is no Fileupload Control version 2.30.

I want to use Fileupload Control in nopCommerce 2.30. Last day I download the

nopCommerce 2.65. Fileupload Control avilable in nopCommerce 2.65.  I changes the

source code 2.30 for implement FileUpload control (reference on 2.6).

Fileupload control rendered succssfully in browser.

[image]

but when I upload a file it's shown a erroe message Please see the Images.

[image]

I and include the **UpdateFileProductAttribute** function in ShoppingCartController in

nopCommerce 2.30 and debug the entire code. Class CatalogSettings In

**FileUploadMaximumSizeBytes** Property is always 0. Please see the image
[image]

And I add the case AttributeControlType.FileUpload: in AddToCartProduct function

in the CatalogController.  but this.Request.Files is null. Please see the Image.
[image]

Is it possible to implement  in Fileupload control in nopCommerce  2.30 ?

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost here. Go to admin area > configuration > all settings. Set value of  CatalogSettings.FileUploadMaximumSizeBytes to 204800 (maximum file size in bytes). If the setting does not exist, create it.

P.S. Do not forget to add locales (such as ShoppingCart.MaximumUploadedFileSize)

Answer (score 2):

Why not go to nopCommerce 2.65?

Comment: Thanks. The existing application in nopCommerce 2.30. I need to implement Fileupload Control in nopCommerce 2.30. Is it possible.

Comment: Yes. But if **FileUploadMaximumSizeBytes** is always **0** it is necessarily impossible to upload a file. By default the value is **204,800**.

Comment: Thank you for your valueable replay.I debug the code frequantly,     I find the  FileUploadMaximumSizeBytes is save in the Database  ( in nopCommerce 2.65). I create new record in database ( in nopCommerce 2.30 ) "Settings" table  create new field  name =  catalogsettings.fileuploadmaximumsizebytes and value = 204800. Now the property shows 204800 value.